# CONCAT'ing NULL fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have a table with three fields, FirstName, LastName and Email.

Here's some dummy data:

```
FirstName | LastName | Email
Adam        West       adam@west.com
Joe         Schmoe     NULL
```

Now, if I do:

```
SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, LastName, Email) as Vitals FROM MEMBERS
```

Vitals for Joe is null, as there is a single null field. How do you overcome this behaviour? Also, is this the default behaviour in MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Try

```
ISNULL(FirstName, '<BlankValue>') -- In SQL Server
IFNULL(Firstname, '<BlankValue>') -- In MySQL
```

So,

```
CONCAT(ISNULL(FirstName,''),ISNULL(LastName,''),ISNULL(Email,'')) -- In SQL Server
CONCAT(IFNULL(FirstName,''),IFNULL(LastName,''),IFNULL(Email,'')) -- In MySQL
```

would return the same thing without the null issue (and a blank string where nulls should be).

Comment: see [BILBO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5792720/532060) about [CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws), a better solution in my opinion

Comment: This doesn't work with MySQL databases... CONCAT_WS() appears to be a more generic solution.

Comment: Note the question is tagged sql-server. Otherwise, you're right.

Answer (score 72):

Look at `CONCAT_WS`

For example:

```
CONCAT_WS('',NULL,"TEST STRING","TEST STRING 2")
```

Yields

`TEST STRINGTEST STRING 2`

This is easier than constructing `IFNULL` around everything.  You can use an empty string as the separator.

Comment: [CONCAT_WS Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

Comment: using it in MySQL, dunno about MS SQL Server tho

Answer (score 12):

In mysql isnull wont work some time. try IFNULL(),

```
CONCAT(IFNULL(FirstName,''),IFNULL(LastName,''),IFNULL(Email,''))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT ISNULL(FirstName,'')+ISNULL(LastName,'')+ISNULL(Email,'') as Vitals FROM MEMBERS
```

is recommended, but if you are really hooked on CONCAT, wrap it in {fn } and you can use the ODBC function like:

```
SELECT {fn CONCAT(ISNULL(FirstName,''), ISNULL(LastName,''), ISNULL(Email,''))} as Vitals FROM MEMBERS
```

If you need first<space>last but just last when first is null you can do this:

```
ISNULL(FirstName+' ','') + ISNULL(LastName,'')
```

I added the space on firstname which might be null -- that would mean the space would only survive if FirstName had a value.

To put them all together with a space between each:

```
RTRIM(ISNULL(Firstname+' ','') + ISNULL(LastName+' ','') + ISNULL(Email,''))
```

Comment: Wouldn't the space on FirstName make the value non-null?

Answer (score 5):

You can always use the `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` setting..

just run `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF` and then all `null` concatenations will result in text and not null..

Answer (score 4):

If you get (like I do in MySQL):

```
#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'
```

You can replace ISNULL function by COALESCE:

```
CONCAT(COALESCE(FirstName,''),COALESCE(LastName,''),COALESCE(Email,''))
```

Answer (score 3):

Stefan's answer is correct.
To probe a little bit deeper you need to know that NULL is not the same as Nothing.  Null represents the absence of a value, or in other words, not defined.  Nothing represents an empty string which IS in fact a value.

Undefined + anything = undefined

Good database tidbit to hold onto!

Answer (score 3):

Starting from  MS SQL Server 2012 it was introduced CONCAT function
and [according to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/hh231515.aspx)

> Null values are implicitly converted to an empty string. If all the
>   arguments are null, an empty string of type varchar(1) is returned.

so it's enough to use CONCAT without IsNull

```
CONCAT(FirstName, LastName, Email)
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server does not have a `CONCAT` function.
(Update: Starting from MS SQL Server 2012 [it was introduced CONCAT function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/hh231515.aspx))

In the default SQL Server behavior, NULLs propagate through an expression.

In SQL Server, one would write:

```
SELECT FirstName + LastName + Email as Vitals FROM MEMBERS
```

If you need to handle `NULL`s:

```
SELECT ISNULL(FirstName, '') + ISNULL(LastName, '') + ISNULL(Email, '') as Vitals FROM MEMBERS
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of MS Access

Option 1) SELECT (FirstName + " " + LastName + " " +  Email) as Vitals FROM MEMBERS
You will get blank result in the case of any field with null.

Option 2) SELECT (FirstName & " " & LastName & " " &  Email) as Vitals FROM MEMBERS
You will get Space in place of field with null.

Answer (score 0):

After observing the answers for this question, you may combine all of them into one simple solution

```
CONCAT_WS(',',
IF(NULLIF(FirstName, '') IS NULL, NULL, FirstName),
IF(NULLIF(LastName, '') IS NULL, NULL, usr_lastname),
IF(NULLIF(Email, '') IS NULL, NULL, Email))
```

**So**, in short we use `CONCAT_WS` to concatenate our fields and separate them with `,`; and notice that `NULL` fields nor `EMPTY` wont concatenated

**NULLIF** will check if the field is `NULL` or `EMPTY`, a field that contains only spaces or is empty as well, ex: '', '    ') and the output will be either `NULL` or `NOT NULL`

**IF** Will out put the field if it's not `NULL` or `EMPTY`