# MySQL Multiple Left Joins with possible empty records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, multiple-tables

So I'm getting into JOINs in MySQL for the first time, and I've got the following setup:

`table: user
fields: id, name, ...other fields...`

and several "group" tables, each with their own unique data, like so

`table: user_group_1
fields: user_id, ...group_1 unique fields...`

`table: user_group_2
fields: user_id, ...group_2 unique fields...`

`table: user_group_X
fields: user_id, ...group_X unique fields...`

I am trying to do a query similar to this:

`SELECT user.name as name, [...etc...], 
        CONCAT( group_a.data_a,',',
                group_b.data_b,',',
                group_c.data_c ) as user_groups
 FROM user
 LEFT JOIN user_group_1 as group_a ON group_a.user_id=user.id
 LEFT JOIN user_group_2 as group_b ON group_b.user_id=user.id
 LEFT JOIN user_group_3 as group_c ON group_c.user_id=user.id`

It works in gathering all the data from my user table, but my user_groups is empty. Now, a user can fall into any number of these groups, so each user may or may not have a record in any or all of these tables.
I'm assuming I'm just using the wrong Join for this. Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: When I query for a user, I need a list of all the group_x.data_x fields in which that user is present. For example, if I query for user.id=1, and I know that user is in group 2, but not group 1 or 3, I want to see user_groups contain: group_b.data_b but instead my user_groups field is empty. 
I am including the extra commas intentionally (rather than using CONCAT_WS) because I need a way to know from which user_group_x field the user_groups data came from.

Comment: use inner join instead.

Comment: Found my problem. I overlooked this little tidibt in the CONCAT documentation:

CONCAT() returns NULL if any argument is NULL.

It looks like CONCAT_WS is the only way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler approach is to use `CONCAT_WS` for this. The first parameter is the separator, which will be interjected between each result. If one of the fields is NULL, then it will be skipped and no separator inserted.

```
SELECT user.name as name, [...etc...], 
        CONCAT_WS(',', group_a.data_a, group_b.data_b, group_c.data_c ) as user_groups
 FROM user
 LEFT JOIN user_group_1 as group_a ON group_a.user_id=user.id
 LEFT JOIN user_group_2 as group_b ON group_b.user_id=user.id
 LEFT JOIN user_group_3 as group_c ON group_c.user_id=user.id
```

see @Bilbo's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035819/concating-null-fields).

and documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws).

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what you're looking for, your query is almost correct. You just missed to check if the group fields are NULL (to avoid an empty [user_groups] column). Here is the fixed query:

```
SELECT user.name as name, [...etc...],
        CONCAT_WS(','
                ,group_a.data_a
                ,group_b.data_b
                ,group_c.data_c) as user_groups
 FROM user
 LEFT JOIN user_group_1 as group_a ON group_a.user_id=user.id
 LEFT JOIN user_group_2 as group_b ON group_b.user_id=user.id
 LEFT JOIN user_group_3 as group_c ON group_c.user_id=user.id
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: If A or B are present, but C is not you are left with a trailing comma.

Comment: You're right, I fixed my query using the CONCAT_WS function.

Comment: Yes.  It now says the same as mine.

Comment: I didn't know this CONCAT_WS function in MySQL, I always work with T-SQL and the approach is a bit different. Great function!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user.name as name, [...etc...], 
        CONCAT( group_a.data_a,',',
                group_b.data_b,',',
                group_c.data_c ) as user_groups
 FROM user
 INNER JOIN user_group_1 as group_a ON group_a.user_id=user.id
 INNER JOIN user_group_2 as group_b ON group_b.user_id=user.id
 INNER JOIN user_group_3 as group_c ON group_c.user_id=user.id
```

Comment: This query will only return users that are in the three groups, i think that it's not the desired result.